# JSONArray converting object to array in Android Can't find tag

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I'm attempting to pull information from an API via JSON on Android. I've successfully downloaded the information, now I need to put it in the JSONArray given the tag "Categories". Ultimately this is going into a listview. Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.util.Log;


public class jsonParser {

    //initialize
    static JSONObject object =null;

    public jsonParser(){

    }

     public JSONObject getJSONfromURL (String url){
            //HTTP call
            try{
                URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 2048 * 16);
                StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                  builder.append(line).append("\n");
                }
                String blah = builder.toString();

                //Parsing string into JSONArray
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject ( new String(builder.toString()) );
                Log.e("success","created object: " + object);

                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("Http Error","Error in http connection " + e.toString());

                }


            return object;
        }
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
05-12 16:57:54.040: E/success(9625): created object: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 16:57:54.040: E/JSON Variable(9625): json returns this value: null
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/Test JSON(9625): JSON s returns: null
05-12 16:57:54.070: W/dalvikvm(9625): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416bf438)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at com.example.hstnc_activity.DisplayServiceActivity$Request.onPostExecute(DisplayServiceActivity.java:104)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at com.example.hstnc_activity.DisplayServiceActivity$Request.onPostExecute(DisplayServiceActivity.java:1)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
05-12 16:57:54.070: E/AndroidRuntime(9625):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Lastly here's the JSON information (used jsonlint.com to grab this):

```
{
    "Categories": [
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Glass Repair"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Appliance Repair"
        },
        {
            "id": "4",
            "name": "Air Conditioning"
        },
        {
            "id": "5",
            "name": "Community Involvement"
        },
        {
            "id": "6",
            "name": "Electrical"
        },
        {
            "id": "7",
            "name": "Flooring"
        },
        {
            "id": "8",
            "name": "Heating Repair"
        },
        {
            "id": "9",
            "name": "Landscaping"
        },
        {
            "id": "10",
            "name": "Plumbing"
        },
        {
            "id": "11",
            "name": "Remodeling/Renovation"
        },
        {
            "id": "12",
            "name": "Window Coverings"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the ASync method:

```
public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
    private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = 
            new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);
        dialog.setMessage("Getting your info real quick... Please wait...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

        json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
        Log.e("JSON Variable", "json returns this value: " + json);

        return json;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {          
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("Test JSON","JSON s returns: " + s);
        try {
            directory = s.getJSONArray("Categories");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< directory.length(); i++){
            String str_id = directory.optString(i, "id");
            String str_name = directory.optString(i, "name");
            displayCatList(str_id, str_name);

            Log.e("Test directory","Directory returns: " + json);
        }

    }

}
```

I appreciate all the help!

Comment: plz also share doInBackground method code

Comment: I added it to the original post.

Comment: I recommend you to use [Spring for Android](http://www.springsource.org/spring-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `data` object from `getJSONFromURL()` method.

Now in `doInBackground()` do this->

```
JSONArray categories = data.getJSONArray("Categories");
```

now here you will have categories array.

You need to initialize your `dialog` under `onPreExecute` like this ->

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Getting your info real quick... Please wait...");
    dialog.show();
}
```

Do this - >

```
public JSONObject getJSONfromURL (String url){
        //HTTP call
        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try{
            URLConnection connection = new URL(url).openConnection();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()), 2048 * 16);
            StringBuffer builder = new StringBuffer();
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
              builder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            String blah = builder.toString();

            //Parsing string into JSONArray
            object = new JSONObject ( new String(builder.toString()) );
            Log.e("success","created object: " + object);

            } catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("Http Error","Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            }


        return object;
    }
```

Comment: I used your advice and the advice below this comment and the app still force closes because json is returning null.

Comment: You were not intialiasing `dialog` properly, I have edited my answer

Comment: Is it solving the problem?

Comment: I updated my code and it's still closing. It has something to do with the json variable returning null I think. I've updated my original post with new code / logcat

Comment: Remove this line from JsonParser class -> //initialize
    static JSONObject object =null;

And change method as I have posted in my answer

Comment: That fixed it returning null! I simply put it in the actual method instead of just the class and it returns how it should! Thank you. It's still not going into the list view as it should but I'll tinker with that and see how it goes.

Comment: I will create new question and tag you. Thank you for all your help thus far!

Comment: Okay..That should be fine..You are welcome...Feels awesome for helping on SO :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16512231/jsonobject-not-displaying-on-listview

Couldn't figure out how to tag so just giving you the link :)

Answer (score 1):

That is array not object. Please use below..

```
        json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
        try {
            JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("Categories");
            for(---){
              //do your stuff
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

as in Log :

> JSONException: No value for Categories

because you are returning `object` `JSONObject` from `getJSONfromURL` method which just contains `id` and `name` keys instead of `Categories` JSONArray.

you can get all values from `object` as :

```
try {
        String str_id = json.optString("id");
        String str_name = json.optString("name");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Ok i redid the code and I still get a force close but the error originally is gone. I've updated my original code snippets and logcat.

Comment: @user1890328 : just move `Log.e("Test JSON","JSON returns: " + json);
        try {
            directory = json.getJSONArray("Categories");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< directory.length(); i++){
            String str_id = directory.optString(i, "id");
            String str_name = directory.optString(i, "name");
            displayCatList(str_id, str_name);
        }` part in onPostExecute and use `s` JSONObject instead of json

Comment: I updated the original post (code and logcat), same issue now s is null and the rest fails because of that.

Comment: @user1890328: make an log also for `json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);` and let me known what u are getting in result

Comment: i added the log and it returns null. I'm updating the code above with this.