# JSONObject not displaying on Listview

Tags: java, android, json, listview

I'm attempting to take a JSONObject and display in listview. The request for the object is returning what it should, it seems the rest of the code isn't working....

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URL;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.JsonReader;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;


public class DisplayServiceActivity extends ListActivity {
    private ListView listOfServices;

    //JSONArrays?
    JSONArray directory;


    //JSON Node names
    private static String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static String TAG_NAME= "name";
    private static String TAG_DIRECTORY = "Categories";
    private final static String url= "APILINKHERE";
    JSONObject json;
    jsonParser jParser = new jsonParser();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> directoryList;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Request request = new Request();
        request.execute();

        listOfServices =getListView(); //get builtin listView


        directoryList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this,
                directoryList, 
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME }, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setContentView(R.layout.service);
        // Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Show the Up button in the action bar.
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }// end of onCreate Method
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public class Request extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

        private static final int REGISTRATION_TIMEOUT = 3 * 1000;
        private static final int WAIT_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000;
        private ProgressDialog dialog = 
                new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(DisplayServiceActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Getting your info real quick... Please wait...");
            dialog.show();
        }

        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {

            json = jParser.getJSONfromURL(url);
            Log.e("JSON Variable", "json returns this value: " + json);

            return json;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {          
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            dialog.dismiss();
            Log.e("Test JSON","JSON s returns: " + s);
            try {
                directory = s.getJSONArray("Categories");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i< directory.length(); i++){
                String str_id = directory.optString(i, "id");
                String str_name = directory.optString(i, "name");
                displayCatList(str_id, str_name);

                Log.e("Test directory","Directory returns: " + json);
            }

        }

    }

    public void displayCatList(String id, String name){                 

        //create new HashMap
        HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        //add each child node to HashMap key
        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

        //adding HashList to ArrarList
        directoryList.add(map);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-12 17:26:33.165: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(10190): <ConfigWindowMatch:2087>: Format RGBA_8888.
05-12 17:26:34.497: E/success(10190): created object: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.497: E/JSON Variable(10190): json returns this value: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.537: E/Test JSON(10190): JSON s returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.537: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.537: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.537: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.547: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.557: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
05-12 17:26:34.557: E/Test directory(10190): Directory returns: {"Categories":[{"id":"2","name":"Glass Repair"},{"id":"3","name":"Appliance Repair"},{"id":"4","name":"Air Conditioning"},{"id":"5","name":"Community Involvement"},{"id":"6","name":"Electrical"},{"id":"7","name":"Flooring"},{"id":"8","name":"Heating Repair"},{"id":"9","name":"Landscaping"},{"id":"10","name":"Plumbing"},{"id":"11","name":"Remodeling\/Renovation"},{"id":"12","name":"Window Coverings"}]}
```

as you can see the JSON info is being pulled, it's just not doing much from there. On the app itself the screen just stays blank without the listview or it being populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AsyncTask executes in BackGround, so till the time `directlyList` getting populated, you were setting it as a listAdapter, you need to `setListAdapter` after population of `directoryList`

You have to `setListAdapter` in `onPostExecute` like this ->

```
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject s) {          
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.e("Test JSON","JSON s returns: " + s);
        try {
            directory = s.getJSONArray("Categories");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< directory.length(); i++){
            String str_id = directory.optString(i, "id");
            String str_name = directory.optString(i, "name");
            displayCatList(str_id, str_name);

            Log.e("Test directory","Directory returns: " + json);
        }
        listOfServices = DisplayServiceActivity.this.getListView(); //get builtin listView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DisplayServiceActivity.this,
            directoryList, 
            R.layout.list_item, 
            new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME }, 
            new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> JSONObject not displaying on Listview

because you are passing  `directoryList` to Adapter before adding items to it.so you will need to create Adapter instance inside `displayCatList` method instead of onCreate method as:

```
 public void displayCatList(String id, String name){                 

        //....your code here

        //adding HashList to ArrarList
        directoryList.add(map);

         // set Adapter for ListView here

          ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(DisplayServiceActivity.this,
                directoryList, 
                R.layout.list_item, 
                new String[] { TAG_ID,TAG_NAME }, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1,android.R.id.text2 });

        DisplayServiceActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are setting the ListAdapter before the JSON data has been retrieved. try setting your listadapter in the `onPostExecute` method and see if that works. Or call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of the list adapter in the `onPostExecute`.

I personnaly always make my own implementation of a list adapter by subclassing `BaseAdapter` in an inner class